# Odd Segue Behaviour - Not Firing

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

So I've noticed some very weird behaviour from my program. Here's a simplified code snippet and then I'll explain what occurs when built and ran.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   ...
   if (self.sampleBool) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
   }
   else {
       // do stuff
   }
}
...
-(IBAction)myMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ...
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

The segue triggers via the UITapGestureRecognizer fine - so I know the segue is linked correctly. However, when self.sampleBool is true and performSegueWithIdentifier is called within viewDidLoad, the segue does not fire.

Anyone have any guesses? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `viewWillAppear` or`viewDidAppear` event and see if it works. My *guess* is that segues in `viewDidload` may not be relevant since things are not entirely wired up.

On the other hand, is there a design issue here? Should that segue be occurring at all if your condition is true? Perhaps you can do your test further upstream before that view is called to load.

Comment: It fires when using `viewDidAppear`. That is so odd. It would seem as though your guess might be bang on! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to push another ViewController inside the ViewDidLoad, you will get problem because in the viewDidLoad, the viewcontroller has not ready yet! Simply way is trying to use the viewWillAppear or viewDidappear.